How to fix lint 'constructor ZipFile(File!)' is deprecated. Deprecated in Javakotlin(DEPRECATION)
In a kotlin codebase, I'm getting the following lint:
'constructor ZipFile(File!)' is deprecated. Deprecated in Javakotlin(DEPRECATION)

for the following minimal code (I've removed everything but relevant lines)
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile
// snip
val tempFile = File.createTempFile("test","file")
val zipFile = ZipFile(tempFile)

The docs state I should "Use ZipFile.Builder.get()" but how do I do this? I'm new to Kotlin/Java and I struggle reading the style of docs used here.

If you see, use ZipFile.Builder.get(), then you should think, "oh, I should use the builder", then explore the API of the builder to see how to use it. Sure, if I was a member of the Apache Commons Compress team, I probably would have chosen to document it more explicitly, but clearly they decided not to.

Yep, and as a non-Java dev the lack of explicit migration docs makes having something here on Stackoverflow helpful

I figured it out in the end, by replacing the line:
val zipFile = ZipFile(tempFile)

with
val zipFile = ZipFile.builder()
                .setFile(tempFile)
                .setUseUnicodeExtraFields(true)
                .get()

I'm not sure whether the .setUseUnicodeExtraFields(true) is a behaviour change or not - it probably doesn't matter in most cases, but this might be a source for differences in behaviour.
